# How to stop graying out of main window menu after activation of child window?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, user-interface, menu

There is a feature in Windows: If current window is not activated, main menu of this window looks disabled (but in fact it is just grayed out, so you can click on any item in this menu). It is ok when you switch to another program, but it looks wrong when you go to child window.

It is easy to reproduce this effect even with standard Notepad:

- Put any text in it,
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>,
- Now you can see that main menu looks disabled, but you can click on any item in it.

[image: Main menu looks disabled]

The question is following: **How to block this effect for my program only?** In my program (C++ and Qt) I have the same graying out of all items in the main menu when user goes to child windows. Is there a way to stop it?

I do not put any code here, because this effect it reproducible in the most of programs. But I hope that it is possible to change flags/properties of my `QMenu` or `QMenuBar` to correct this behavior. Is it possible?

Comment: What is actually happening is that when a window does not have the input focus, its menu is drawn grayed, as if it is disabled. There is no way to invoke the menu without setting input focus to the window. When you click on a menu item, it sets input focus to the window (taking the focus off of the popup dialog), which is why the menu items are drawn as enabled again. If you click on a menu item, then press Esc twice to dismiss the menu, you'll find that the window containing the menu remains focused. So all you've done is changed the focus by clicking!

Comment: There isn't much you can do about the way the built-in menu support works.  It is not inappropriate, they are not going to work when you use the keyboard to select menu entries.  Pressing the Alt key does not display the cues and Alt+F does not select File.  Modeless dialogs are in general rather a usability headache.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, thank you, I absoultely agree that it is strange to show menu as active when Alt key does not works (i.e. when this menu is inactive). But it was what customer need. Sometimes we have to do such things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can correct a palette of the `QMenuBar` to substitute a text color in inactive state with text color in active state.

The code:

```
QPalette pal = pMenuBar->palette();
QColor col = pal.color(QPalette::Active, QPalette::ButtonText);
pal.setColor(QPalette::Inactive, QPalette::ButtonText, col);
pMenuBar->setPalette(pal);
```

After it user will not see graying out of items in a main menu, because text colors of active and inactive items will be the same.

(Theoretically it is possible that background color of active and inactive states of the same item are different. So it might be reasanoble to make the same replacement for background too)

Comment: I was going to ask how this could possibly work, if you're not using a palletized color mode (which you are surely not). But then I looked up the documentation for QPalette, and found out that this is some Qt-specific nonsense. "All widgets in Qt contain a palette and use their palette to draw themselves." Right, because nothing in Qt is actually a native control, which is why the library is broken and the applications it produces are crappy, and why asking for advice about Windows programming when you're using Qt is a bit of a crapshoot. I assumed from your screenshots you were using Win32.

Comment: Also, do keep in mind that clients typically *think* they want things, but it is your job as their hired expert to explain to them why that they think they want doesn't make sense. The purpose of Hans's and my comments were to explain to you enough so that you could explain it to them. Sometimes programmers get mixed up and think it is their sole job to do exactly what the client wants. But we are not trained monkeys. We are hired to think and design, because we know what we're doing. If you ship something to a client that is confusing or unusable, they have every right to blame you.

Comment: @CodyGray Thank you!