# Menubar sometimes does not become un-greyed when QFileDialog closes

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, windows-10, qfiledialog

OS: W10. This may be significant. If you have different results on a different platform, feedback would be helpful.

Here is an MRE. If you run it and go Ctrl+O, the menu labels become greyed. If you select a file in the `QFileDialog` by clicking the "Open" button or using its mnemonic (Alt+O), the open-file dialog is dismissed and the "Files" and "Help" menus become un-greyed.

However, if you go Ctrl+O again, and this time enter the name of a file in the "File name" box (`QLineEdit`), and then press Return, the dialog is dismissed (with a successful selection result) but the "Files" and "Help" menus remain greyed-out. It looks like this:

[image]

```
import sys, os 
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Greying of menus MRE')
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 100, 400, 200))

        menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(self)
        self.setMenuBar(menubar)
        self.files_menu = QtWidgets.QMenu('&Files', self)
        menubar.addMenu(self.files_menu)
        self.help_menu = QtWidgets.QMenu('&Help', self)
        menubar.addMenu(self.help_menu)
        self.new_action = QtWidgets.QAction('&New', self)
        self.files_menu.addAction(self.new_action)
        self.open_action = QtWidgets.QAction('&Open', self)
        self.files_menu.addAction(self.open_action)
        self.open_action.setShortcut("Ctrl+O")
        self.open_action.triggered.connect(self.open_file)
                
    def focusInEvent(self, event ):
        print('main_window focusInEvent')
        super().focusInEvent(event)

    def focusOutEvent(self, event ):
        print('main_window focusOutEvent')
        super().focusInEvent(event)
        
    def activateWindow(self):
        print('main_window activateWindow')
        super().activateWindow()    
        
    def open_file(self):
        print('open file')
        
        main_window_self = self

        # open_doc_dialog = QtWidgets.QFileDialog(self.get_main_window())
        class OpenDocFileDialog(QtWidgets.QFileDialog):
            def accepted(self):
                print('accepted')
                super().accepted()

            def accept(self):
                print('accept')
                super().accept()
        
            def close(self):
                print('close')
                super().close()
        
            def done(self, r):
                print(f'done r {r}')
                
                # neither of these solves the problem:
                # main_window_self.activateWindow()
                # main_window_self.files_menu.activateWindow()
                super().done(r)
        
            def hide(self):
                print(f'hide')
                super().hide()
                
            def focusInEvent(self, event ):
                print('focusInEvent')
                super().focusInEvent(event)
        
            def focusOutEvent(self, event ):
                print('focusOutEvent')
                super().focusInEvent(event)
                
            def activateWindow(self):
                print('activateWindow')
                super().activateWindow()    
                
        
        open_doc_dialog = OpenDocFileDialog(self)
        open_doc_dialog.setWindowTitle('Choose file')
        open_doc_dialog.setDirectory(os.getcwd())
        # we cannot use the native dialog, because we need control over the UI
        options = open_doc_dialog.Options(open_doc_dialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
        open_doc_dialog.setOptions(options)
        open_doc_button = open_doc_dialog.findChild(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox).button(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Open)
        lineEdit = open_doc_dialog.findChild(QtWidgets.QLineEdit)
        
        # this does not solve the problem
        # lineEdit.returnPressed.disconnect()
        # lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(open_doc_button.click)
        
        print(f'open_doc_button {open_doc_button}, lineEdit {lineEdit}')
        # show the dialog
        dialog_code = open_doc_dialog.exec()
        if dialog_code != QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted: return
        sel_files = open_doc_dialog.selectedFiles()
        print(f'sel_files: {sel_files}')

                
app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
main_window = MainWindow()
main_window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

This problem can be understood, if not solved, with reference to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38244126/595305).

Note that this greying-out is not disablement. As explained in the above link, this has to do with "active/inactive states" of the menus (or their labels). The menus remain enabled throughout, although in this case it's impossible to know that while the open-file dialog is showing because it is modal. Clicking on one menu after the dialog has gone, or just hovering over it, is enough to un-grey them both...

The explanation, as I understand it, is that the "File name" box `QLineEdit` has a signal, `returnPressed`, which appears to activate something subtley different to the slot which is invoked when you use the "Choose" button. You can see I have experimented with trying to re-wire that signal, to no avail.

The method `done` of the `QFileDialog` appears to be called however the dialog closes (unlike `close`!), so I tried "activating" the main window... and then the individual `QMenu`s... Doesn't work.

I am not clear how to get a handle on this "active state" business or why the slot connected to `returnPressed` is (seemingly) unable to give the "active state" back to the menus when the other slot manages to do so.

**Edit**
Searching on Musicamante's "unpolishing" suggestion led me to this:

```
lineEdit.returnPressed.disconnect()
def return_pressed():
    style = main_window_self.menubar.style()
    style.unpolish(main_window_self.menubar)
    open_doc_button.click()
lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(return_pressed)
```

... unfortunately this doesn't work.

Comment: The linked question doesn't seem to be completely related, since the issue there is about non blocking dialogs (and it's the correct behavior by design). Can you confirm the same behavior also for the static methods of QFileDialog, both native and not? In the meantime, as a workaround, you can force a repaint on the menu bar by unpolishing it as soon as the dialog is closed.

Comment: Thanks. The problem does not occur with a native file-chooser. I just meant that the other question is related in the sense that without finding it I would still be scratching my head even more, as I have not heard of this "active/inactive state" of a `QWidget`. Could you please explain what you mean by this "unpolishing" technique? Perhaps you might put that as an answer?

Comment: @mikerodent I can't seem to reproduce this on linux, but I may be misunderstanding the problem. From what I can make out, the problem is that the main-window remains inactive when the dialog is closed. But is it *truly* inactive, or does it just appear that way? That is, can you interact with the window using **only** the keyboard immediately after closing the dialog, or is it that the window just doesn't repaint properly?

Comment: Ah, maybe another Windoze "singularity". Yes, it is completely about appearances! Keyboard interaction works fine, and in fact going Alt-F after the dialog is closed not only displays the "Files" menu's menu items, but also "re-activates" the labels of both menus. PS sorry about missing imports: will amend!

Comment: Looks like a bug, then. If you're going try a work-around that forces a repaint, you will probably need to wait until the event-loop returns control to the main-window. A [single-shot timer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#singleShot) with a small delay might do the trick.

Comment: @ekhumoro OK... just off the top of your head, what might I need to put into this deferred code before going `menubar.repaint()`? Is it something along the lines of the `QStyle.unpolish()` thing I tried?

Comment: The exact incantation may be platform-specific, so you may need to experiment a bit by calling `polish()`, `unpolish()`, etc in various ways.

Comment: @ekhumoro ... finally, no deferred timer needed: see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a possible Windows-related bug, since I can't reproduce it on Linux. As a work-around, you could try forcing a repaint after the dialog closes:

```
# show the dialog
dialog_code = open_doc_dialog.exec()
self.menubar.repaint()
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it, thanks to Musicamante's suggestion:

```
lineEdit.returnPressed.disconnect()
def return_pressed():
    style = main_window_self.menubar.style()
    style.unpolish(main_window_self.menubar)
    open_doc_button.click()
    main_window_self.menubar.repaint()
lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(return_pressed)
```

... I actually tried this several times, just to make sure it was doing what was intended. So in fact, fortunately, no single-shot timer was needed in this case.

Comment: I suspect most of that code is unnecessary. Why not just do the repaint after `exec()` returns? (Also, I only suggested the single-shot timer because you originally said this solution didn't work - so it's not really relevant any more).

Comment: Right again: just doing `self.menubar.repaint()` after `exec` is the answer: you might want to put that as an answer as it'd be much more relevant for future viewers...

Comment: Well, you did most of the actual work - we just offered a few hints ;-) You as well just accept your own answer.

Comment: Haha, I'm not sure I can agree: I would NEVER have come up with that one-liner after `exec`, and I can be pretty sure about that! I'll give it an hour or so for you to decide whether you'd like the points, after which I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @mikerodent I suggested the unpolish because I wasn't sure (and, as ekhumoro and I suggested, you only need that after the `exec`) , but remember that it's rarely required: most of the times you only need it when changing something on the style (including changing properties used as selectors in the stylesheet, since they are only evaluated once); usually before going for that, you might try, in order, a simple `update`, or `repaint` (both of them on the *specific* widget, which means, for instance, the viewport of a scroll area based widget, like item views, graphics views or text areas).